# Override a shape using IShapeTableProvider

Tags: .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I want to override `Container.cshtml` view in this path: `Orchard.Core\Containers(folder)\Views\EditorTemplates\Container.cshtml` 
to my view in this path:
 `MyModule\\Views\EditorTemplates\MyContainer.cshtml`

 

 
now!, I implemented `IShapeTableProvider` Interface for this purpose:

```
public class MyShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
    {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Describe("Container")
                .OnDisplaying(displaying =>
                {
                    displaying.ShapeMetadata.Alternates
                        .Add("Container_MyContainer");
                });
        }
    }
```

the code is call in staring time of the project, but don't work it!
Is't correct or not?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Why implement shapetableprovider for this? If you just put a Container.cshtml in Views/EditorTemplates it will take over

Comment: And your view is called MyContainer.cshtml, but it will search for a Container.MyContainer.cshtml

Comment: @devqon: I don' want to change this view in the Core module. when I create the same name view (Container.cshtml) in my module , orchard call the container view in the Core. the priority of calling is with the core module

Comment: If you add a dependency in your module.txt: `Dependencies: Containers` then your module will get the priority

Comment: @devqon: wow, it's work it!.it's great man! ...it's take me two days!...very very thanks...

Comment: @devqon: thanks again, but how does it work? Why adding `Dependencies: Containers` to the  module.txt change the priority?

Comment: Because then it tells Orchard I am taking the functionality of this module, but gonna change some things. This way your module always overrides anything defined in the Dependencies section

Comment: @devqon: it's great. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let your module take precedence, you have to lay a dependency on the module to override in your module.txt:

```
Dependencies: Containers
```

This way you let Orchard know that you want to use the module's functionality, and you are able to override it.